# MS Access 2016: Avoiding entering the same data multiple times

Tags: vba, ms-access

one of my table keeps track of assets that has been assigned to different customers. For example, I have a field named "Location" which is a list of devices and a field name "Customer"

The 1st 2 or 3 letters of "Location" is unique to the Customer's name, for example let's say the customer name is "All About Customers", my Location will be AAC001, AAC002, etc. The sequence continues indefinitely.

When adding records, I would type AAC010, AAC011, AAC012, etc. and then I would have to select from a drop down box which customer these belongs to, if I'm adding 40 records, I'd have to select the same customer 40 times.

Is there away to let access know which Customer I'm preferring to based on the 1st 2 or 3 letters of my location?

Comment: This cannot be answerd since you did not say how this could work. If you have a rule (which explains how it works to match a 3 letters code to a specific customer) or a table that maches the 3 letters with a customer then it would be possible to do, otherwise not. • Anyway your question is a way too broad to give you an answer. Please read [ask] and maybe reading [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) helps too.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, I have a "Customers" table too, in there I could have a column that specify the prefix "AAC" for customer All About Customers, and I can get this to work, but I'm not sure about the sequential numbers that must follow this prefix.

Comment: *"I'm not sure about the sequential numbers that must follow this prefix"* What does this mean? Actually your question is a way too broad and too less details. • Actually the question was *"Is there away to let … based on the 1st 2 or 3 letters of my location?"* and the answer is: Probably yes. • So if you wanted to ask something else please use the [edit] button and improve your question. Also add more details and what you have thought how this would work.

Comment: Use a bound form for your customer data and a bound subform to allocate an asset to a customer. Base your subform on a separate table to reflect customer assets, using Cutomer ID as a foreign key). Link form and subform through Customer ID. There's absolutely no need for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: And what if you have another customer named "And Another Customer", i.e. the initials are the same? This is a poor schema for an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Not gonna talk about the flaws in this approach in terms of database modelling and rules etc.

But to do some vba code, you just have to define the OnChange event of the desired control e.g. TextBox
Whenever there is a character entered you could execute code.
(in example it would happen only if text has 3 or more characters)

```vb
Public Sub OnChange()
    If Len(Textbox) >= 3 Then
       'Do Something
    End If
end Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My time is limited right now, so I can only provide you with my approach and not the actual code:

I would create a separate table named Customers.
The table should have the two fields (test data in parentheses):

customer (All About Customer, The Store)

customerAbbreviation (AAC, TS)

On your form, there should be a macro fired after the update of the form's Location field.

The macro should have some type of code that separates the numbers and text in the Location field. Using All About Company as an example, the macro should return AAC and 001.

You could search the Customers table for the customer whose customerAbbreviation is AAC.

You could then set the form's Customer field to the All About Company, or whatever's returned in the above line.